# ReactRedux array prop empty

Tags: arrays, reactjs, redux, native

I'm quite new to React and have searched through so many StackOverflow responses but with no joy. So when an array of employees is passed to a reducer and then a component, the prop is empty the first time and then contains data on subsequent renders. Does anyone know how to prevent react rendering until the employees props contains data?

--------Update

So i added isloading to the reducer initial state and tried to send it to the component but i receive a really horrible error

TypeError: In this environment the sources for assign MUST be an object. This error is a performance optimization and not spec compliant

this is my updated case statement

```
case EMPLOYEES_FETCH_SUCCESS:
 return {

 list: action.payload, 
    isloading: false 

}
```

[New error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/75u1L.png)

Many thanks

the data array looks like this when it is populated

[data structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WEtsV.png)

Reducer code:

```
import { EMPLOYEES_FETCH_SUCCESS, USER_ADD } from "../actions/types";

const INITIAL_STATE = {};

export default (state = INITIAL_STATE, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case EMPLOYEES_FETCH_SUCCESS:
      return action.payload;

    case USER_ADD:
      return state;

    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

this is my action dispatch statement

```
dispatch({ type: EMPLOYEES_FETCH_SUCCESS, payload: returnArray });
```

Component code:

```
  componentWillMount() {
    this.props.employeesFetch();

    this.createDataSource(this.props);
  }

  componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    this.createDataSource(nextProps);
  }

  createDataSource({ employees }) {
    const ds = new ListView.DataSource({
      rowHasChanged: (r1, r2) => r1 !== r2
    });

    this.dataSource = ds.cloneWithRows(employees);
  }

  onButtonPress() {
    Actions.GroupChatContainer(); //Need to send bar's chat record
  }

  renderRow(employee) {
    return <ListItem employee={employee} />;
  }

  render() {
    console.log(this.props.employees);

    return (
      <View>
        <ListView
          style={styles.listStyle}
          enableEmptySections
          dataSource={this.dataSource}
          renderRow={this.renderRow}
        />

        <Button onPress={this.onButtonPress.bind(this)}>Group chat</Button>
      </View>
    );
  }
}


const mapStateToProps = state => {
console.log(state.employees);


  const employees = _.map(state.employees, (val, uid) => {
    return { ...val, uid };
  });

  return { employees };

};
```

Answer (score 0):

> Does anyone know how to prevent react rendering until the employees
>   props contain data?

Sure, just do a check and return null:

```
render() {
  if (!this.props.employees) {
    return null;
  }

  return (
    <View>
      <ListView
        style={styles.listStyle}
        enableEmptySections
        dataSource={this.dataSource}
        renderRow={this.renderRow}
      />

      <Button onPress={this.onButtonPress.bind(this)}>Group chat</Button>
    </View>
  );
}
```

Or inside JSX:

```
render() {    
  return (
    <View>
      {this.props.employees &&
        <ListView
          style={styles.listStyle}
          enableEmptySections
          dataSource={this.dataSource}
          renderRow={this.renderRow}
        />
      }

      <Button onPress={this.onButtonPress.bind(this)}>Group chat</Button>
    </View>
  );
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply Tomasz. unfortunately  none of those suggestions work.  My code enters this if statement twice  "if (!this.props.employees) "with a empty array

Comment: Only if i navigate back to the previous screen and then reenter the list screen does the array of data get populated

Answer (score 0):

You can have two properties for your store. One for the list of employees and another for the loading state.

```
import { EMPLOYEES_FETCH_SUCCESS, USER_ADD } from "../actions/types";

const INITIAL_STATE = {
   list: [],
   isLoading: true,
};

export default (state = INITIAL_STATE, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case EMPLOYEES_FETCH_SUCCESS:
      return {
         list: action.payload,
         isLoading: false,
      }

    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

And in the `render` if the state is loading return loading view

```
render() {
  if (!this.props.employees.isLoading) {
    return <div>Loading...</div>;
  }
  ...
  ...  
}
```

Comment: Thank you Arun. I receive this error: type error in this environment the sources for assign must be an object.